# Find top N receipt records that fulfill quantity on hand

Tags: sql, t-sql

Below is data for a particular part. The `OnHand` is the same amount for all records in this example because the example is for one part.

```
OnHand     DateReceived    QuantityReceived     
24         2013-04-17           20
24         2013-04-01           12
24         2013-03-10           12
24         2013-03-01           12
```

I need to find the rows from the received purchase orders for that part that add up to the quantity on hand. So, in the example above, I should get the top 2 records because the quantity on hand is 24, and that amount is accounted for by the receipt of 20 and then the receipt of 12 pieces.

How can I do this?

I have tried limiting my results by a running total:

```
where (select SUM(QuantityReceived) from table t where t.ReceivedDate >= table.ReceivedDate)<=table.OnHand
```

But that only returns the first row.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Post your SQL statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                SUM(quantityReceived) OVER (ORDER BY dateReceived DESC) psum
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   onHand > psum - quantityReceived
```

In earlier versions:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable m
WHERE   onhand >
        (
        SELECT  SUM(quantityReceived)
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.dateReceived >= m.dateReceived
        ) - quantityReceived
```